# Installing expect with thread enabled tcl on Fedora 25

Tags: linux, multithreading, tcl, expect, fedora

I need thread-enabled tcl and also expect on Fedora 25. I downloaded tcl from https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html.

I configured with './configure --enable-threads' and did 'make', 'make install'.  I was able to get 'package require Thread' working with tclsh8.6.

I wanted expect as well. So, did 'yum install expect'. It installed new tclsh.  Now I have tclsh8.6(only thread working and no expect) and also tclsh(only expect working and no thread).

Can someone help me to get one tclsh with thread and expect working.

thanks in advance
uv.

Comment: also build Expect from source and link to your new built tcl86.